# How to clear some of the search cache in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser, bookmarks, browser-cache

When you bookmark or visit a specific site, Chrome will start suggesting it when you start typing letters that that site URL starts with

e.g. I often visited, or bookmarked:

```
https://coolsite.com/some-specific-page?q=something
```

When I start typing in a new tab, anything starting with ***"cool..."*** - Chrome will suggest and fill in the entire URL, containing the whole endpoint path, query params etc., like this

```
https://coolsite.com/some-specific-page?q=something
```

How can I, ideally, change what URL Chrome suggests e.g. change `https://coolsite.com/some-specific-page?q=something` to `https://coolsite.com/something-else`

or how do you at least, delete this specific entry from the Chrome cache/suggestions, without clearing out the whole history?

Comment: Any luck, I am having a similar issue!